# Как удалить код который не использую из jquery?

Tags: jquery

Как удалить код который не использую из jquery?? или  код с других библиотек которые используются

Comment: Непонятна суть вопроса.

Comment: подключаю библиотеку jquery там 5к кода из них я использую 1к как мне удалить то что мне не пригодилось?

Comment: Ну блин, удаляйте и все. Что сложного то?

Comment: А вообще нормальные люди используют jquery как она есть. Зачем вам вообще удалять? Ничего быстрее работать не будет.

Comment: подключено несколько библиотек выходит 10к кода из них и половины не задействовано на страницах. Думаю от пары тысяч страница будет грузится быстрее

Comment: На одну сотую секунды — да, будет грузиться быстрее. Но смысл? Вы так вообще всю библиотеку испортите своими удалениями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем? Если вопрос в оптимизации - то это плохая идея.
Первая причина, удаленные методы и свойства могут использоваться в других методах jQuery.
Вторая причина, потеряете 100% гарантию в поддержке уже существующих плагинов